# How to remove headers and telnet information in SonarQube?

Tags: apache-http-server

For security reasons we need to remove the information showed when the SonarQube server is reaching using a telnet command. This operation is commonly called [Banner grabbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_grabbing).

SonarQube is a java application and it seems to run under a apache/catalina server but I wasn't able to find the server.xml file to solve this problem.

Anyone knows how to configure the server for SonarQube to achieve this goal?

```
$> telnet sonarqubeserver 9000

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 13 Jul 2016 17:34:39 GMT
Connection: close
```

I need to remove this **Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1**.

In a normal java application running under **Apache**, we can do this in the **server.xml** file but I can't find it inside the sonarqube folder.